# Get the ID of authenticated user with passport

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I have a database set up with mongoose and the authentication works via passport (passport-local-mongoose). That works fine, however, I want to get the ID of the current authenticated user so that I can use it as a condition for updating the database. Unfortunately I only know how to check if the user is authenticated in general. Here is the rough structure of what I want to do:

```
app.post("/updateUser", (req, res) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        Users.updateOne(
        {
            _id: //get identity of authenticated user
        }, 
        {
            test: "works!"
        }, 
        err => { ... });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to take it by request from user
`app.post("/updateUser", (req, res) => {if(req.isAuthenticated()){Users.updateOne({ _id: req.id  }, { test: "works!"},  err => { ... }); }});`

Comment: `req.id` did'nt work, but I just needed to add "user" in between: `req.user.id`. Thank you anyway!